# Use Batch to determine the ACTIVE Video Card GPU

Tags: batch-file

We have some computers that have an integrated graphics card along with out NVIDIA graphics card. Some members are running 3D CAD tools while the integrated graphics card is active. Is there a way for me to use a batch script to check which graphics card is ACTIVE? **wmic path win32_VideoController get name** only gives me a list of graphics cards, not the active one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is from the dxdiag, the first video card listed is the selected one.

```
@echo off
REM Check current selected display 1 and 2
set vcard=''
start "" /w dxdiag /t "%cd%\display.txt"
find "Card name" display.txt | find /V "---------- DISPLAY.TXT" > output.txt
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=:" %%a in (output.txt) do set vcard=%%a
del display.txt /f
del output.txt /f
echo %vcard%
```

Answer (score 1):

another way is using wmic and get the display with the value of maxrefresh it means its the active one.

sample code below:
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%f in ('wmic path Win32_VideoController where MaxRefreshRate^>0 get name /value ^| find "="  ') do set "vcpri=%%f"

Comment: Thank you! We are getting there. MyWin32_VideoController doesn't include MaxRefreshRate capability. Just:

AcceleratorCapabilities  AdapterCompatibility  AdapterDACType     AdapterRAM  Availability  CapabilityDescriptions  Caption                 ColorTableEntries  ConfigManagerErrorCode  ConfigManagerUserConfig  CreationClassName      CurrentBitsPerPixel  CurrentHorizontalResolution  CurrentNumberOfColors  CurrentNumberOfColumns  CurrentNumberOfRows  CurrentRefreshRate  CurrentScanMode  CurrentVerticalResolution  Description             DeviceID          DeviceSpecificPens  DitherType

Comment: and
DriverDate                 DriverVersion  ErrorCleared  ErrorDescription  ICMIntent  ICMMethod  InfFilename  InfSection  InstallDate  InstalledDisplayDrivers

Comment: Its there type the command below:

"wmic path Win32_Videocontroller get MaxRefreshRate, Name /value"


MaxRefreshRate=60
Name=Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics

But for my task, the value > 1 is better for me. Some cards without MaxRefreshRate will show blank value

Comment: Its there type the command below:

"wmic path Win32_Videocontroller get MaxRefreshRate, Name /value"


The result for me are below:

MaxRefreshRate=
Name=NVIDIA Quadro P2200


MaxRefreshRate=64
Name=ASPEED Graphics Family(WDDM)


But for my task, the value > 1 is better for me. Some cards without MaxRefreshRate will show blank value. Then I use the condition MaxRefreshRate>1

Comment: Paul, I checked with a few users and some have both with Max Refresh values over 0. Some have their active graphics card without any value, but all had their active card first. Maybe I can run a for loop and just use the first item on the list when calling "wmic path Win32_Videocontroller get Name /value" 
What do you think? Can we assume the first item IS the active card?

Comment: After doing some testing, it appears that after switching to the other graphics card, the position does NOT switch. I feel like we are sooo close!

Comment: Weird, in my case. The task was to get the primary card. And with the command, the primary card will have the max refresh value > 1. Its not always the first item on the list. On my case the MaxRefreshRate which have > 1 (usually the values i get for the primary video card and monitor will be 60, 64 or 75). If the display with the adapter is not active (or its not selected) its value is null or 0

Comment: In my case the servers that I am checking the primary card / monitor selected is always active. Maybe with yours its in sleep/standby mode? I tried running the command  and when i change the primary displays the value always change to the > 60 on the selected card.

Comment: Its the not the position. Its the MaxRefreshRate

Comment: I saw what you mean that the value doest change. After changing the display, give it a few seconds (maybe 15-30 secs) the MaxRefreshRate will change.

Comment: Paul, I really appreciate your help. Unfortunately, some of our users: have 2 graphics cards where one of them doesn't have MaxRefreshRate and others who have both cards with a MaxRefreshRate over 0. I'm still scratching my head here :(.

Comment: Are they both nvidia cards? you can use nvidia-smi then. The graphic card that has the status On, is the one currently connected.

Comment: Try to download the MultimonitorTool.exe from nirsoft. And see the values changing when changing the cards

Comment: one is an Nvidia and the other is an integrated intel graphics. Can the nvidia-SMI show off if the intel graphics is being used? I'd prefer not to convince IT to install another tool. Could be a lot of red tape.

Comment: nvidia-smi will not show other brands. The multimonitorTool is just  for the test to see the values when changing the primary card or display. Btw, there is another command wmic path Win32_DesktopMonitor get Name, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, Status,PNPDeviceID, the one active monitor will have value on screenwidth and screenheight

Comment: Thank you Paul. What is the correlation between the active monitor and the active graphics card?

Comment: the display attached to the primary video card, has values.

Comment: Paul, maybe I am missing something. But how do I find out if they are using Nvidia or integrated graphics?

Comment: I think they are related with the PNP device, btw. win32_VideoController, should be enough for you. can you generate a text output result for win32_VideoController? selecting the the video cards and generating the values for win32_VideoController?

Comment: Yes, but we can't figure out how to determine the active current GPU.

Comment: can you show the maxrefreshrate value when you select one of the cards and the other?

Comment: No. The maxrefreshrate  is not consistent between all of our users. Some have graphics cards that use it, others don't.

Comment: hello for the ones without maxrefreshrate, can you test to use the multimonitortool just to see the properties of the display and the vcard?

Comment: Since I am not officially part of IT, I would like to refrain from downloading and installing other tools.

Comment: I see then the only way for you is the dxdiag